# Markov Chain: Turn a problem into a markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

We have 2 machines, which are working in 0.75 precent if it wasn't out o order the day before.
When a machine goes out of order, it takes 2 days to fix her up.
let Xn be the num of working machines in day n (including those who were back from repairing).

Now I know this situation doesn't describe a markov chain, because the dependence on the 2 days repairing time.
How would you describe the situation to make it a markov chain?

Thanks!

Comment: can you add dimensions to record past information as current information?

Comment: by dimensions you are talking about representing the machine which is in repairing this day? if so, I think yes.